# How to do text justification?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to randomly add spaces in a string up to the string being a total of 80 characters long. For some reason, my program just isn't working. Am I missing something here? It only inputs spaces in the same position, not randomly :/.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::string; using std::endl;

const int line_width = 80;

int main()
{
    //declare string and get user input
    string not_justified;
    cout << "Input a line of text less than 80 characters to be justfied: " << endl;
    getline(cin, not_justified);

    int position = not_justified.find(' ');

    //start random number generator
    srand(time(nullptr));

    while (not_justified.size() != line_width)
    {
        //find space position
        position = not_justified.find(' ');

        //get random number from 1-80
        int random_number = rand() % 80 + 1;

        //test to see if number is less than 40, if it is return true
        random_number < 40 ? true : false;

        //if true, insert a space
        if (true)
            not_justified.insert(position, " ");

        position += position;
    }

    cout << "Your justified line is: " << not_justified << endl;
} //end main
```

My output looks like this:

```
Input : My name is bob

OutPut: Debug Error! abort() has been called
```

Comment: Step through the code line by line in a debugger. The reason should become apparent.

Comment: Why are you using a random number?  My understanding is that justification depends on the words in the line and the width of the line, no need for random numbers.

Comment: I'm using a random number because I don't need the spaces to be spread uniformly so randomness seemed to be the next best option.

Comment: replace  "random_number < 40 ? true : false;  if (true)" with   "if(random_number < 40)"

Comment: `position` is always the position of the first space character. `if (true)`: well, `true` is always `true`. The entire code of your loop is equivalent to `not_justified.insert(not_justified.find(' '), " ");`

Comment: Alrighty, I took the advice everyone offered and now the spaces seem to appear randomly but my program crashes if I run it. I'm not sure what is causing that :/

Comment: Why do you `rand() % 80 + 1` ??? you have to add space to the actual space positions provided in the source string, not everywhere.  Just get the positions of the input spaces and select one based on random (or better, distribute them uniformly widening the input spaces)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I really hate the fact I'm unable to comment unless I have more than 50 reputation; therefore most of my input consists of assumptions.

**What you did wrong**

Firstly, you're always going to be emplacing the space at the same position, at the first (actually implementation-defined) space position. Which, for the string `"My name is Bob"` would be at positon `2`.

Secondly, Your random generator contributes nothing as to where the space insertion happens.

Lastly, your method of checking wether or not the randomly generated number is within limits is incorrect. This statement `random_number < 40 ? true : false;` is useless, it doesn't contribute or change the behaviour of your code at all, and is likely optimized away by the compiler. You should also note, that `random_number < 40` does the exact same thing, but with less code pollution.

**Fixed code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random> 
#include <vector>

using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::string; using std::endl;

const int line_width = 80;

std::vector<size_t> find_all_of( const std::string &str, const char &what = ' ' )
{
    auto count = 0u;
    std::vector<size_t> result;
    for ( auto &elem : str )
    {
        if ( elem == what )
            result.emplace_back( count );
        ++count;
    }
    return result;
}

int main( )
{
    //declare string and get user input
    string not_justified;
    cout << "Input a line of text less than 80 characters to be justfied: " << endl;
    getline( cin, not_justified );

    std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device( )( ) }; // random number generator
    while ( not_justified.size( ) < line_width )
    {
        auto spaces = find_all_of( not_justified ); // find all of the current spaces
        std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution{ 0, spaces.size( ) - 1 }; // only allow results within the bounds of spaces
        auto where = spaces[distribution( rng )];  // select a random position using the distribution method
        not_justified.insert( where, " " ); // insert it.
    }
    cout << "Your justified line is: " << not_justified << endl;
    cin.get( );
} //end main
```

**Other points**

`rand()` is considered harmful. [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Comment: Hi @yamiez, can you update your answer to give some high level details as to `rand()` is considered harmful. Some key points from the video you linked is all that's needed. Reason being is that in case the video disappears, it still has contextual relevance to your answer.